# cakePHP 2.x connecting to a remote database using key

Tags: database, cakephp-2.1

I need to get connected with a mysql database on a different server, i have the RSA key to connect to the server and i also have all the credentials needed to connect to the database, and using this following codes, i am able to get connected perfectly

```
try {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->sqlUser, $this->sqlPass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    shell_exec("ssh -i /path/to/rsa/key/the_key myusername@some.ip.address -L3307:localhost:3306 -N");
};

try {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->sqlUser, $this->sqlPass);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage() . " (line:" . __LINE__ . ")");
};
```

however, i am building the application using cakePHP 2.x, how can i connect to that remote server and database using cakePHP's configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i manage to do this by creating an extended class called FarAwayMysql.php under app/Model/DataSource/Database

```
App::uses('DboSource', 'Model/Datasource');

class FarAwayMysql extends DboSource {
public $description = "Faraway MySQL DBO Driver";

protected $_baseConfig = array(
    'persistent' => true,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'cake',
    'port' => '3306',
    'rsa' => '',
    'remote_username' => '',
    'remote_ip' => ''
);
protected $_connection = null;

protected $_useAlias = true;

public function connect() {
    $config = $this->config;
    $this->connected = false;
    try {
        $flags = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $config['persistent'],
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        if (!empty($config['encoding'])) {
            $flags[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES ' . $config['encoding'];
        }
        if (empty($config['unix_socket'])) {
            $dsn = "mysql:host={$config['host']};port={$config['port']};dbname={$config['database']}";
        } else {
            $dsn = "mysql:unix_socket={$config['unix_socket']};dbname={$config['database']}";
        }
        $this->_connection = new PDO(
            $dsn,
            $config['login'],
            $config['password'],
            $flags
        );
        $this->connected = true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "ssh -i {$config['rsa']} {$config['remote_username']}@{$config['remote_ip']} -L3307:{$config['host']}:3306 -N";
        shell_exec("ssh -i {$config['rsa']} {$config['remote_username']}@{$config['remote_ip']} -L3307:{$config['host']}:3306 -N");
    }


    try {
        $flags = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $config['persistent'],
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        if (!empty($config['encoding'])) {
            $flags[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES ' . $config['encoding'];
        }
        if (empty($config['unix_socket'])) {
            $dsn = "mysql:host={$config['host']};port={$config['port']};dbname={$config['database']}";
        } else {
            $dsn = "mysql:unix_socket={$config['unix_socket']};dbname={$config['database']}";
        }
        $this->_connection = new PDO(
            $dsn,
            $config['login'],
            $config['password'],
            $flags
        );
        $this->connected = true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {             
        throw new MissingConnectionException(array(
            'class' => get_class($this),
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ));
    }

    $this->_useAlias = (bool)version_compare($this->getVersion(), "4.1", ">=");

    return $this->connected;
}
}
```

by adding 3 new configs

```
protected $_baseConfig = array(
    'persistent' => true,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'cake',
    'port' => '3306',
    'rsa' => '',
    'remote_username' => '',
    'remote_ip' => ''
);
```

and then on your app/Config/database.php, it would be

```
public $faraway = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/FarAwayMysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'faraway_username',
    'password' => 'faraway_password',
    'database' => 'faraway_db_name',
    'port' => '',
    'rsa' => 'path/to/rsa/key',
    'remote_username' => 'your_username',
    'remote_ip' => 'your.ip.address'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your post. I use `PostgreSQL` instead of `MySQL` so made some adjustments. Some of it may be relevant to `MySQL` too.

1. when shell_exec'ing, redirect output to `/dev/null` and run in background. Also ports changed from `3306/3307` to `5432/5433`

   shell_exec("ssh -i {$config['rsa']} {$config['remote_username']}@{$config['remote_ip']} -L5433:{$config['host']}:5432 -N > /dev/null &")
2. `FarAwayPostgres.php` is as follows

   true,
                    'host'                  => 'localhost',
                    'login'                 => 'root',
                    'password'              => '',
                    'database'              => 'cake',
                    'port'                  => '5432',
                    'rsa'                   => '',
                    'remote_username'       => '',
                    'remote_ip'             => '',
                    'sslmode'               => 'allow',
                    'schema'                => 'public',
                    'flags'                 => array()
            );

            protected $_connection = null;
            protected $_useAlias = true;

            public function connect() {

                    $config = $this->config;
                    $this->connected = false;

                    $flags = $config['flags'] + array(
                            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $config['persistent'],
                            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                    );

                    try {
                            if (empty($config['unix_socket'])) {
                                    $dsn = "pgsql:host={$config['host']};port={$config['port']};dbname={$config['database']};sslmode={$config['sslmode']}";
                            } else {
                                    $dsn = "pgsql:unix_socket={$config['unix_socket']};dbname={$config['database']}";
                            }

                            $this->_connection = new PDO( $dsn, $config['login'], $config['password'], $flags);
                            $this->connected = true;
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            $cmd="ssh -i {$config['rsa']} {$config['remote_username']}@{$config['remote_ip']} -L5433:{$config['host']}:5432 -N > /dev/null &";
                            shell_exec($cmd);
                            sleep(3);
                    }


                    try {
                            if (empty($config['unix_socket'])) {
                                    $dsn = "pgsql:host={$config['host']};port={$config['port']};dbname={$config['database']};sslmode={$config['sslmode']}";
                            } else {
                                    $dsn = "pgsql:unix_socket={$config['unix_socket']};dbname={$config['database']}";
                            }

                            $this->_connection = new PDO( $dsn, $config['login'], $config['password'], $flags);
                            $this->connected = true;
                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            throw new MissingConnectionException(array(
                                    'class' => get_class($this),
                                    'message' => $e->getMessage()
                            ));
                    }

                    return $this->connected;
            }
    }

Note how a three second sleep has been inserted so that connection attempt to database waits for ssh to finish.

Finally, `database.php`:

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

        public $default = array(
                'datasource'      => 'Database/FarAwayPostgres',
                'persistent'      => false,
                'host'            => 'localhost',
                'port'            => '5433',
                'login'           => 'postgres',
                'password'        => '',
                'database'        => 'remote_db',
                'rsa'             => '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa',
                'remote_username' => 'root',
                'remote_ip'       => 'remote_server',
                'prefix'          => '',
                'encoding'        => 'utf8',
        );
```

The private key `id_rsa` sits in Apache's home dir and is readable by `Apache`.

Now, finally, prior to use, perform the following:

```
su -m apache
ssh -i /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa root@remote_server
```

in order to update `known_hosts`.